# Multi-level grouping in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I need multi-level grouping. Is it built into jqGrid? Is it a planned future feature?

If not, does someone have an idea of creating a work-around without having to modify the plug-in directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really need** multi-level grouping you can implement it on the server side. If you need some interface to toggle of groups like jqGrid as do you can examine [the source code of jrGrid](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.grouping.js#L166). It seems to me that you can achieve the close effects using [tree grids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#tree_grid).

About the plans of implementing multi-level grouping in jqGrid - it is definitively wrong place for such question. You should ask the question on [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393).

Answer (score 2):

Multi Grouping is now supported in jqGrid 4.4.0

> We are happy to announce the fresh new jqGrid 4.4 release. This
>   release adds new functionality and bug fixes. Here is what is new:
>
> - Multigrouping support – this add a grouping on more than one field
> - Performance optimizations
> - A LOT of fixes.
>
> The documentation and examples are up to date. You can see it in the
>   appropriate pages. The examples are in Grouping item in demo and are
>   marked as (new)

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=974

Answer (score 1):

Another and easy way of increasing any number of levels(dimensions) in Jqgrid is by adding setGroupHeaders that number of times

If my columns are like, ColNames = ['Id','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'];

Now add setGroupHeaders Like

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'id', numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: '.'},
    {startColumnName: 'date', numberOfColumns: 8, titleText: 'Nice'},
    ]   
});
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'id', numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: '.'},
    {startColumnName: 'date', numberOfColumns: 4, titleText: 'rice'},
    {startColumnName: 'total', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'dice'}
    ]   
});

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'id', numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: '.'},
    {startColumnName: 'date', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Price'},
    {startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Shiping'},
    {startColumnName: 'total', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'bipping'}
    ]   
});
```

Following is the output

```
| .  |                       Nice                              |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| .  |                 rice                |       dice        |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| .  |       Price     |      Shipping     |       bipping     |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  Date  | Client |  Amount   |  Tax  | Total  |  Notes   |
```